# Selectize.js not working

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm trying to integrate selectize.js on my projectI tried an example that has nothing to do with my project, but somehow it didn't work. I don't get any error on my console what am i missing?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>teste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectize.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <select id = "input-tags">
       <option value = "1">Carro</option>
       <option value = "2">Moto</option>
   </select>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="selectize.js"></script>
    <sctipt src="teste.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('select').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:
`<sctipt src="teste.js"...` rather than
`<script src="teste.js"...`

Comment: no problemo, happens to everyone. Always nice to have a second pair of eyes!